# Is it possible to load only selected columns from Avro file to Hive?

Tags: hive, avro

I have a requirement to load Avro file to hive. Using the following to create the table
***create external table tblName stored as avro location 'hdfs://host/pathToData' tblproperties ('avro.schema.url'='/hdfsPathTo/schema.avsc');***

I am getting an error ***FOUND NULL, EXPECTED STRING*** while doing a select on the table. Is it possible to load few columns and find which column data is causing this error?

Comment: This is not a free code writing service. What did you try so far? Please [edit] your question and post your code as a [mcve]! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need first to create an Hive External table pointing to the location of your AVRO files, and using the AvroSerDe format.
At this stage, nothing is loaded. The external table is just a mask on files.
Then you can create an internal HIVE  table and load data (the expected columns) from the external one.

Comment: Its not possible to load the file. While loading I am getting an error Found null, expected string. Hence want to filter few columns and check which column data causing the error

Comment: Do you get the message when you create the table or when you execute a SELECT on it ?  Please use a proper formatting to copy/paste your code.
Also the Avro URL must start by `hdfs://clusteralias/. `

Comment: Error occurs while executing SELECT. The CREATE statement works fine and all the attributes defined in the table are of string type

Answer (score 0):

If you are already having AVRO file, then load the file to HDFS in a directory of your choice. Next create an external table on top of the directory.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE external_table_name(col1 string, col2 string, col3 string ) STORED AS AVRO LOCATION '<HDFS location>';
```

Next create an internal hive table on top of the external table to load the data

```
CREATE TABLE internal_table_name(col2 string, col3 string) AS SELECT col2, col3 FROM external_table_name
```

You can schedule the internal table load using a batch script in any scripting language or tools.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Its not possible to load the file. While loading I am getting an error Found null, expected string. Hence want to filter few columns and check which column data causing the error